# Why does my webpack bundle cut off when I'm running vagrant on Virtualbox?

Tags: webpack, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm running a phoenix/elixir dev server on vagrant using webpack to compile and watch my JS files. But my bundle that's being passed to localhost is only getting partially built; it cuts off in the middle of the file, sometimes in the middle of a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is most likely memory. Webpack's dev watch will serve files from memory and if you're just using the default memory that your vagrant gave you, you most likely don't have enough.

You should go into your virtualbox's settings and up the systems base memory.

To do this:

1. Halt your vagrant with `vagrant halt`
2. Open up virtual box
3. Click on Settings (the gear in the top bar)
4. Go to the "System tab"
5. Move the memory slider to the right.
6. Start your vagrant again with `vagrant up`.

Hopefully all should be good now!